# How to get a date from DatePickerController Flutter

Tags: flutter, controller

I am using a Date_Picker_Timeline  and I want to get Access to the chosen date afterwards.
(import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';)

Usally I used TextEditingController where I just typed controller.text, but with my DatePickerController thats not possible.

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Best Regards
Musiker

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ghs/util/my_button.dart';
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';


class DialogBox extends StatelessWidget {

  final controllerKlinik;
  final controllerDate;
  DateTime selectedDate;
  VoidCallback onSave;
  VoidCallback onCancel;

  DialogBox({
    super.key,
    required this.controllerKlinik,
    required this.controllerDate,
    required this.onSave,
    required this.onCancel,
    required this.selectedDate,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(252, 170, 0, 1.0),
      content: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            // get user input Date
            DatePicker(
              DateTime.now(),
              initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)),
              selectionColor: Colors.black,
              selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
              controller: controllerDate,
            ),
            //get user input Klinik
            TextField(
              controller: controllerKlinik,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              border:OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Datum'
              ),
            ),

            //buttons --> save + cancel
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                //save button
                MyButton(text: 'Save', onPressed: onSave),
                const SizedBox(width: 8,),
                //cancel button
                MyButton(text: 'Cancel', onPressed: onCancel),
              ],
            )
          ],
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ghs/util/dialog_box.dart';
import 'package:ghs/util/time_tile.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  //text controller
  final _controllerKlinik = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerDate = DatePickerController();
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  //list of working hours
  List workingshift = [
    [DateTime(2023,1,1), 8, 'Beispielklinik' ],
    [DateTime(2023,12,12), 6, 'Beispielklinik2' ],
  ];

  // save new working shift
  void saveNewWorkingShift(){
    setState(() {
      workingshift.add([_selectedDate, 7,_controllerKlinik.text]);
      _controllerKlinik.clear();
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  // create new working shift
  void createNewWorkingShift() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return DialogBox(
            controllerKlinik: _controllerKlinik,
            controllerDate: _controllerDate,
            selectedDate: _selectedDate,
            onSave: saveNewWorkingShift,
            onCancel: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          );
        },
    );
  }

  // delete working shift
  void deleteWorkingShift(int index){
    setState(() {
      workingshift.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Zeiterfassung'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: createNewWorkingShift,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: workingshift.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return TimeTile(
              date: workingshift[index][0],
              workingHours: workingshift[index][1],
              klinik: workingshift[index][2],
              deleteFunction: (context) => deleteWorkingShift(index),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I created a AlterDialog where the Timeline shows up and it looks really cool. But I have no idea how to get the Date.

I tried to use a controllerDate = DatePickerController(); and I tried to use the "onDateChange" method which is in the constructor of the DatePicker which I imported.
The controller for the Textfield works fine, but I cant just type DatePickerController.date to access the date.
I will post my Code as well, but I really want to understand. Would be really nice if someone could explain to me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use value notifier for this. Replace the `_selectedDate` in HomePage with

`final ValueNotifier<DateTime> _selectedDate = ValueNotifier(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3)));`,

And in DialogBox add onDateChange like this :-

```
        DatePicker(
          DateTime.now(),
          initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3)),
          selectionColor: Colors.black,
          selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
          controller: controllerDate,
          onDateChange: (DateTime date) {
            selectedDate.value = date;
          },
        ),
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My first attempt didnt work. But I will try the way with ValueNotifier. Do I need a ValueListenableBuilder for every ValueNotifier?

Comment: In this case you don't have to use ValueListenableBuilder.